# Clarify makefile syntax

Tags: linux, makefile

Could someone clarify how this code works?

```
PRE_PROC_EXE        := $(shell which pre_proc.pl)
PRE_PROC2_EXE       := $(shell which pre_proc2.pl)

$(filter $(TMP_DIR)/%.c,$(FILES)):$(TMP_DIR)/%.c: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(PRE_PROC_EXE) < $< > $@
```

I was trying to add one more step of pre processing on the files generated by step one (using `PRE_PROC2_EXE`). How do I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to use `PRE_PROC2_EXE` in the same recipe or in its own recipe? Does it take streamed input or files directly? Do you want a second set of intermediate files?

Comment: I need a second set of intermediate files, since it is run like
`./pre_proc2.pl in_file > out_file`

Comment: Do you want a second make rule? That would need another set of entries in `$(FILES)` or another make variable, etc. or do you just want to run both commands in that one rule?

Comment: I was thinking making `PRE_PROC_EXE` generate temp files in `TMP_DIR` with names  `*.temp.c`. And do `PRE_PROC2_EXE` on those files.

Comment: That works but means you need to be a bit more careful about cleaning up after yourself if you do it in one rule because make doesn't know about those recipe-internal files at all.

Comment: `$(PRE_PROC_EXE) < $< | $(PRE_PROC2_EXE) > $@` like Norman suggested seems the easiest cleanest way to do it then. I can rewrite `PRE_PROC2_EXE` to accept stream input since it is under my control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(shell)` is a make function which runs a shell command and returns its output.

So `PRE_PROC_EXE` contains the output from running `which pre_proc.pl` and `PRE_PROC2_EXE` contains the output from running `which pre_proc2.pl`. (I'll point out that `which` isn't portable, isn't guaranteed to exist and doesn't have a specification for its behavior so you can't rely on its output so using it like this isn't a great idea.)

The rest is a [Static Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) which operates on the entries in `$(FILES)` that match the `$(TMP_DIR)/%.c` pattern (from `$(filter $(TMP_DIR)/%.c,$(FILES))`) and applies the recipe to them using the matching `$(SRC_DIR)/%.c` file as the prerequisite (`$<`) and the matching `$(TMP_DIR)/%.c` file as the target (`$@`).

As to how to apply `PRE_PROC2_EXE` to this that isn't easily answerable as you haven't explained how that script works or how you need to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

How does that work? It works by magic! – in my opinion, that's an awful bit of Makefile (practical remarks at the end).

`make` is a simple system, with simple syntax, which does one thing well.  Over the years, however, it has acquired (and yes, I'm looking at you, GNU Make) a crust of elaborate functions, with compressed syntax, and a vast manual, which together make some Makefiles look like line-noise.  Such as here.

Sometimes you have to do more-or-less clever things to build a bit of software, but (in my opinion and experience) these are much more naturally and comprehensibly handled by adding sophistication to the *rules*, not the Makefile syntax itself.  That way, you leave the *structure* of the Makefile reasonably intelligible, which is important if you need to understand and adjust how the software is built.

I write quite complicated Makefiles, but only occasionally use a filter as complicated as `patsubst` (but I do generally use GNU Make – BSD/POSIX Make is an asceticism too far).

Also, you could use auxiliary tools to do certain parts of the heavy lifting.  For example, you might use [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) to do the tool-searching, write

```
PRE_PROC_EXE=@PRE_PROC_EXE@
PRE_PROC_EXE2=@PRE_PROC_EXE2@
```

in a `Makefile.in`, and write a `configure.ac` which includes

```
dnl  Process this file with autoconf
AC_INIT(fooprog, 0.1-SNAPSHOT, author@example.org)

AC_PATH_PROG(PRE_PROC_EXE, pre_proc.pl, NOT_FOUND)
AC_PATH_PROG(PRE_PROC_EXE2, pre_proc2.pl, NOT_FOUND)

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Then `autoconf; ./configure` would find `pre_proc{,2}.pl` and substitute them into a new `Makefile`.  `autoconf` takes a little getting used to, first time, but is pretty natural once you get used to it.

Returning to your particular example, I have little idea what that target does (two colons? I don't want to know...), but you might be able to adjust the rule to

```
$(PRE_PROC_EXE) < $< | $(PRE_PROC_EXE2) > $@
```

to pass the input `*.c` files through both preprocessors.

Comment: Lol.. `make some Makefiles look like line-noise` This is exactly what I thought.